# What is the best way to have multi-language "log messages" in Django?

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

In my Django application users interact via a series of web forms and a log is generated. The log may, for example, look something like this:

1. Battle has begun!
2. Attacker (Elver) used Whirlwind. It was super effective!
3. Defender (Angeleyes) built a moat. Defense +5.
4. A storm has broken out. Attacker (Elver) misses a turn.

The problem is that this log should be displayed in other languages as well. And if a new language is added, previous log messages must automatically also display in the new language.

As you can see there are multiple types of messages (event without params, event with params, attack event, construction event, etc.)

What is the best data structure to store these in so that they would be easily translatable based on simple templates?

My thinking originally was to build a separate model for each event. For example class AttackEvent(models.Model) with fields attacker, spell, result. But these would have to refer back to some battle so that it would be easy to query for all of them and sort them as well. Could they all refer back to that battle using a ForeignKey with the same related_name? Probably not.

Another option would be to have a huge GenericLogEvent class that has an insane number of params with most of them blank=True, null=True. and then we switch based on eventType.

What's the best way here?

Comment: I'm not a big django developper but for me, use django message contrib and a templatetag to render yours may be great... you may want to use a json database field to have all your parameters... in this case may be message contrib will not be relevent.

Answer (score 3):

I’d store the message and the parameters (have a look at [django-picklefield](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield)) in your log message model, and use Django’s built in [translation stuff](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/internationalization/) to translate messages into other languages.

Comment: This looks like a pretty good way of doing it. Thanks! Although I am worried about the performance hit of unpickling and rendering 100+ log messages... I guess since they're immutable, they can be easily cached.